# Connecting to a remote database using java

Tags: java, database

I am planing to but a web hosting package to host a site which shows customer details to the customers who will be registered with that web site. I have a java application which runs in my local computer which I am going to update the database of my hosted web site.
What in need to know is, is that possible to connect to the databases which we are buying from the web hosting package sellers from our locally running java applications?

Comment: why not? if you have the port open in the firewall configuration, then in your java application, you can specify the ip address and connect to the db which is hosted in the dc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: is it possible to connect to the databases which we are buying from the web hosting package sellers from our locally running java applications?

A: No: not usually.

At a *MINIMUM*, you need at *LEAST* two things:

1) RDBMS-specific client software (including, but not necessarily limited to, the relevant JDBC driver(s)) loaded on to *EACH* client PC

... and ...

2) All firewalls between the remote RDBMS server and each of your client PCs must be open to your RDBMS protocol (for example, port 1433 for MS Sql Server).

It's much more common for your web app, web server and RDBMS to be co-located, and your clients simply communicate via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to connect to remote databases using java applications. The `JDBC API` will help you to create tables, insert values, query the tables, retrieve the results of the queries, and update the tables.

As far as a remote connection is concerned, here are two good links to begin with:

1) [Link 1](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/738b7897-cd38-4f24-9f05-48dd69116837/entry/programmatically_connecting_to_remote_systems2?lang=en)

2) [Link 2](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/dist/ch07_02.htm)

You haven't specified the type of database you need to connect to. Depending upon that you can learn how to create data sources, database roles etc as shown over [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e10589/urls.htm).